# maximum number of partitions on the iscsi volume

Tags: storage, partition, iscsi

What is the maximum number of partitions that can be created on the ISCSI volume? 
I need the solution for both Windows and Linux platform considering 1 TB available to both.

Answer (score 0):

The number of partitions you can create on a volume is unrelated to whether that volume is local or remote via iSCSI. An iSCSI volume becomes just another local disc once a session is created.